# DateTime format error, Copy Activity. Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am copying data from CSV to Azure MySQL. I've a date field  with format MM/DD/YYYY in source. It is throwing an error while copying data to MySQL. I tried changing the datatype in field mapping, pipeline ran succesfulbut data is not loaded. I need to convert the format to YYYY-MM-DD.

"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "'Type=MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,Message=Incorrect date value: '12/06/2010' for column 'xxx_dt' at row 49,Source=MySqlConnector,''Type=MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,Message=Incorrect date value: '12/06/2010' for column 'XXX_DT' at row 49,Source=MySqlConnector,'",
"failureType": "UserError",

Please suggect.

thanks.

Comment: Hi Geetha, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory can not convert date format from 'MM/DD/YYYY' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' directly.

If you want convert the date format from 'MM/DD/YYYY' to 'YYYY-MM-DD', please using [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) with [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column).

For example, I have csv file with the column date format with "MM/DD/YYYY":
[image]

I use Data Flow with bellow Derived Column expression:

```
toDate(concat(split({ born},'/')[3],'-',split({ born},'/')[1],'-',split({ born},'/')[2]))
```

[image]

The column `born` is convert to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format:
[image]

You could follow my steps.